# Devise devise_error_messages! shows up without any event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `devise_helper.rb` file where I have:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    'Looks like you missing a password'
  end
end
```

But whenever I go to `/user/sign_up`, it shows up. I wonder why that's still showing up without an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [devise helper file](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb)

devise_error_messages! is just a stub. You need to override it with your own implementation of the error messages you want or copy the views to your app and change them to your preference. It looks like you are just printing out 'Looks like you missing a password' the way you have it now. Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: well even if i remove the devise_helper.rb file, it still shows the message -`Password can't be blank` .not sure whats happening